# Light and Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, reference-frames, observers

If an object is in motion that means time slows down for the observer in motion. So if there is a planet that is 1 billion light years away that is moving away from us does that mean we are seeing that planet 1 billion years in the past? Or do we see it at a different moment in time all together? Also would that planet appear to be slowed down or sped up to us? Or would time appear to be passing at the same rate that it does for us?

Comment: `If an object is in motion that means time slows down for the observer in motion`. This statement isn't true. It's more true if the object is accelerating. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rietdijk%E2%80%93Putnam_argument#Andromeda_paradox doesn't answer your question but may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The time on the moving planet is for them the same as for us. So he half-life of a radioactive materiel will be the same. we would judge here time slowed down and the the same for our time.
And yes we are seeing n it 1 billion years in the past in our time scale.